# Render plot based on plot type selection from user

Tags: shiny

I'm developing an R Shiny App to interact with forest inventory data and I want to create a process where a user selects either a Histogram or Box Plot from the sidebar interface and Shiny generates the selected plot in the main panel.

Below is my current code for the Shiny App with some generated data that outputs both the Histogram and Box plots. I would like for only one of these to be generated based on the user input in the sidebar panel:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

setwd(getwd())

# Prep CFI Data
cfi <- data.frame(total_BA = rnorm(200, 90, 20),
                  all_QMD = rnorm(200, 8, 1.2),
                  class1 = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), times = 50),
                  class2 = rep(c('D', 'S'), times = 100)) %>% 
  mutate_at(c('class1', 'class2'), as.factor)

##### User-Interface #####
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("CFI Viewer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel title",
                 
                 selectInput("plot.type",
                             label = "Select plot type",
                             choices = c('Histogram', 'Box Plot'),
                             selected = "Histogram"),
                 
                 selectInput("var",
                             label = "Choose a variable to display",
                             choices = colnames(cfi[, c(1:2)]),
                             selected = "total_BA"),
                 
                 sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                             label = "Select # of bins for histogram",
                             min = 5,
                             max = 50,
                             value = 15),
                 
                 selectInput(inputId = "fac",
                             label = "Choose a factor for box plot",
                             choices = c('class1', 'class2'),
                             selected = 'class1')
    ),
    
    mainPanel("main panel title",
              
              fluidRow(plotOutput('hist')),
              
              fluidRow(tableOutput('hist.sum')),
              
              fluidRow(plotOutput('box')),
              
              fluidRow(tableOutput('box.sum'))
    )
  )
)


##### Server #####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$hist <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(cfi, aes(x = get(input$var))) + 
      geom_histogram(bins = input$bins, color = "black", fill="darkgray") 
  })
  
  output$hist.sum <- renderTable({
    cfi %>% 
      summarize(Min = min(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                Q1 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
                Median = median(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                Mean = mean(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                Q3 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
                Max = max(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                NAs = sum(is.na(get(input$var)))
      )
  })
  
  output$box <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(cfi, aes(x = get(input$fac), y = get(input$var))) + 
      geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
      stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 19, size = 2, na.rm = TRUE)
  })
  
  output$box.sum <- renderTable({
    box.sum <- cfi %>% 
      group_by(get(input$fac)) %>% 
      summarize(Min = min(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                Q1 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
                Median = median(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                Mean = mean(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                Q3 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
                Max = max(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                N = n())
    colnames(box.sum) <- c(input$fac, 'Min', 'Q1', 'Median', 'Mean', 'Q3', 'Max', 'N')
    box.sum
  })
  
}


##### Launch App #####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `observeEvent` to observe and act based on the user selection to toggle between the plots. I have modified your code to switch between the histogram and box plot based on the dropdown selection.

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

setwd(getwd())

# Prep CFI Data
cfi <- data.frame(total_BA = rnorm(200, 90, 20),
                  all_QMD = rnorm(200, 8, 1.2),
                  class1 = rep(c(1, 2, 3, 4), times = 50),
                  class2 = rep(c('D', 'S'), times = 100)) %>% 
  mutate_at(c('class1', 'class2'), as.factor)

##### User-Interface #####
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("CFI Viewer"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel("sidebar panel title",
                 
                 selectInput("plot.type",
                             label = "Select plot type",
                             choices = c('Histogram', 'Box Plot'),
                             selected = "Histogram"),
                 
                 selectInput("var",
                             label = "Choose a variable to display",
                             choices = colnames(cfi[, c(1:2)]),
                             selected = "total_BA"),
                 
                 sliderInput(inputId = "bins",
                             label = "Select # of bins for histogram",
                             min = 5,
                             max = 50,
                             value = 15),
                 
                 selectInput(inputId = "fac",
                             label = "Choose a factor for box plot",
                             choices = c('class1', 'class2'),
                             selected = 'class1')
    ),
    
    mainPanel("main panel title",
              
              fluidRow(plotOutput('plot')),
              
              fluidRow(tableOutput('data.sum'))
            
    )
  )
)


##### Server #####
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$plot.type,{
    if(input$plot.type == 'Histogram'){
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        
        ggplot(cfi, aes(x = get(input$var))) + 
          geom_histogram(bins = input$bins, color = "black", fill="darkgray") 
      })
      
      output$data.sum <- renderTable({
        cfi %>% 
          summarize(Min = min(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    Q1 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
                    Median = median(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    Mean = mean(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    Q3 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
                    Max = max(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    NAs = sum(is.na(get(input$var)))
          )
      })
      
    } else if(input$plot.type == 'Box Plot'){
      output$plot <- renderPlot({
        ggplot(cfi, aes(x = get(input$fac), y = get(input$var))) + 
          geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
          stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "point", shape = 19, size = 2, na.rm = TRUE)
      })
      
      output$data.sum <- renderTable({
        box.sum <- cfi %>% 
          group_by(get(input$fac)) %>% 
          summarize(Min = min(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    Q1 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
                    Median = median(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    Mean = mean(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    Q3 = quantile(get(input$var), 0.75, na.rm = TRUE),
                    Max = max(get(input$var), na.rm = TRUE),
                    N = n())
        colnames(box.sum) <- c(input$fac, 'Min', 'Q1', 'Median', 'Mean', 'Q3', 'Max', 'N')
        box.sum
      })
    }
  })
  
}


##### Launch App #####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```